How to convert a html, css and javascript website to pwa
I made a website called Rodenttube and added a manifest.
Unfortunaltely it isn't installable.
Got the manifest from the following site.
https://dev.to/developertharun/convert-any-website-into-a-pwa-in-just-3-simple-steps-35pp
This is my html and manifest code.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rodenttube</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/Rodenttube%20logo.png">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Gratis knaagdierparodys voor iedereen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <style>
        #video-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 98%;
            gap: 2%;
        }

        video {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px; 
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            #video-container {
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 49%);
            }
        }
        body{
         background-image: url(images/hout%20bg.jpg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
  <p style="text-align:center;"><img class="logo" src="images/Rodenttube logo.png"/ height="300px" width="300px"></img></p>

    <h1 style="color: #654321; -webkit-text-stroke: 2px darkgreen; text-align: center;">Rodenttube</h1>
    <div style="border: 4px solid black;" id="video-container">
    <video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Ik ben ricardo de bever.jpg"
        src="videos/ik ben ricardo de bever.mp4">
    </video>
     <video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/we gaan naar Friesland.jpg" src="videos/we gaan naar friesland.mp4">
</video>
       <video preload="none" controls playsinline   poster="images/money.jpg" src="videos/had je heel veel poen.mp4">
</video>
      <video preload="none" controls playsinline    poster="images/kon ik nog maar 1 dag in het bos zijn.jpg" src="videos/kon ik nog maar 1 dag in het bos zijn.mp4">
</video>
    <video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/Zonder Rodenttube.png" src="videos/Zonder Rodenttube.mp4">
</video>
    <video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/Ik ben ricardo.png" src="videos/ik ben ricardo.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/knaagdierjournaal video 3.png" src="videos/knaagdierjournaal video 3.mp4">
</video>
     <video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/verkiezingsdabat 1.png" src="videos/verkiezingsdabat 1.mp4">
</video>
      <video preload="none" controls playsinline    poster="images/zij knaagt met mij.png" src="videos/Zij knaagt met mij.mp4">
</video>
        <video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/knaagdierjournaal video 2.png" src="videos/knaagdierjournaal 2.mp4">
</video>
      <video preload="none" controls playsinline    poster="images/ricardo-bij-klantenservice.png" src="videos/ricardo-bij-klantenservice.mp4">
</video>
       <video preload="none" controls playsinline   poster="images/Bart de bever.png" src="videos/Wie is Bart zijn beste vriend.mp4">
</video>
       <video preload="none" controls playsinline   poster="images/terry-boadam.png" src="videos/terry-boadam-strijd-voor-het-knagen.mp4">
</video>
    <video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/les-huis-anubis-1.jpg" src="videos/les-huis-anubis-1.mp4">
</video>
      <video preload="none" controls playsinline    poster="images/The-forest-is-ours.jpg" src="videos/The-forest-is-ours.mp4">
</video>
       <video preload="none" controls playsinline   poster="images/knaagdierjournaal video 1.webp" src="videos/Knaagdierjournaal video 1.mp4">
</video>
     <video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Iedereen volgt de trends.png" src="videos/Iedereen volgt de trends.mp4">
</video>
       <video preload="none" controls playsinline   poster="images/Dit is de realitijd.png" src="videos/Dit is de realitijd.mp4">
</video>
   <video preload="none" controls playsinline   poster="images/I wish you a lot of beachnuts.png" src="videos/I wish you a lot of beachnuts.mp4">
</video>
<video  preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/knagen is goud.png" src="videos/knagen is goud.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/Jij knaagt te veel.png" src="videos/jij knaagt te veel.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/Drukke beverdans.png" src="videos/Drukke beverdans.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/mag niet meer knagen.png" src="videos/mag niet meer knagen.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/we gaan met de familie naar het beverbos.png" src="videos/we gaan met de familie naar het beverbos.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline  poster="images/mijn zoon knaagt bomen.png" src="videos/Mijn zoon knaagt bomen.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/I nibble wood in the snow.jpg" src="videos/I nibble wood in the snow.mp4">
</video>
    <video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Bomen knagen.jpg" src="videos/Bomen knagen.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/What is so nice about Rodenttube.jpg" src="videos/What is so nice about Rodenttube.mp4">
    </video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Bartje knaagt graag hout.jpg" src="videos/Bartje knaagt graag hout.mp4">
    </video>
    <video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/knagen is lit.jpg" src="videos/Knagen is lit.mp4">
    </video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/De klas gebruikt AI.jpg" src="videos/De klas gebruikt AI.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Dit is Rodenttube.jpg" src="videos/Dit is Rodenttube.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Kerstbever.jpg" src="videos/kerstbever.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Wedden.jpg" src="videos/Wedden.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Ik wens je veel beukennoten.jpg" src="videos/Ik wens je veel beukennoten.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Oja lele parodie.jpg" src="videos/Oja lele parodie.mp4">
</video>
<video preload="none" controls playsinline poster="images/Knagen zij aan zij.jpg" src="videos/Knagen zij aan zij.mp4">
</video>
    </div>

    <script>
        var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
        var currentIndex = 0;

        function selectVideo(index) {
            videos.forEach((video) => {
                video.style.border = 'none';
                video.pause();
            });

            var currentVideo = videos[index];
            currentVideo.style.border = '4px solid red';
            currentVideo.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
            currentVideo.play();
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            var columns = window.innerWidth >= 768 ? 2 : 1;

            switch (event.key) {
                case 'ArrowRight':
                    if ((currentIndex + 1) % columns !== 0 && currentIndex + 1 < videos.length) {
                        currentIndex++;
                        selectVideo(currentIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'ArrowLeft':
                    if (currentIndex % columns !== 0) {
                        currentIndex--;
                        selectVideo(currentIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'ArrowDown':
                    if (currentIndex + columns < videos.length) {
                        currentIndex += columns;
                        selectVideo(currentIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'ArrowUp':
                    if (currentIndex - columns >= 0) {
                        currentIndex -= columns;
                        selectVideo(currentIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Enter':
                    var currentVideo = videos[currentIndex];
                    if (currentVideo.paused) {
                        currentVideo.play();
                    } else {
                        currentVideo.pause();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });

        selectVideo(currentIndex);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Manifest
{
    "name": "Rodenttube by FC Knaagdier",
    "short_name": "Rodenttube",
    "start_url": "index.html",
    "scope": "./",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "images/Rodenttube%20logo.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#654321",
    "background_color": "#654321",
    "display": "standalone"
  }


I looked on the internet and followed the first two steps of this article. https://dev.to/developertharun/convert-any-website-into-a-pwa-in-just-3-simple-steps-35pp
And I asked on Discod for help. They recoomended stack overflow.

You could have a look at Google's or Mozilla's websites, there's more content there than we could ever hope to produce here.

Shameless plug. I made a github template for creating PWAs, that might help you. Following the advice you get from Lighthouse is also really helpful.
